# IDLE shutdown when pressing '

Tags: python, python-idle

I downloaded IDLE to program using Python. But when I try to use a ' create strings, it automatically closes the IDLE. What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions to read [the link posted there in that warning message](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) and do what it tells you: install an up-to-date version of Tcl/Tk 8.5, like [that from ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads).  You're running into [an old bug in the OS X Cocoa-based Tk](http://sourceforge.net/p/tktoolkit/bugs/2722/) that still exists in the old version Apple ships with OS X.

Comment: I already did that, but still closes

Comment: Did you install Tcl/Tk 8.5.x as it tells you to?  If you installed Tcl/Tk 8.6.x it won't help.

Comment: It says that the actual version installed of Tcl/Tk its 8.5.9.
There is a new version. 8.5.18, but I already installed it, but it keeps telling me that the version installed it's the 8.5.9

http://i.imgur.com/TMdogSr.png

Comment: Have you quit and restarted IDLE since installing 8.5.18?  From the version information, I can tell that you've installed Python 3.4.3 from the latest python.org 64-/32-bit installer (an installer I manufactured).  I can promise you that it will work with ActiveState Tcl/Tk 8.5.18 if both Python and ActiveTcl are properly installed.